# Angular.js local development environment setup questions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have completed a few tutorials on Angular.js and I am ready to start building from scratch locally, but I am not able to successfully setup my local development environment.

I copied the package.json from Angular's tutorial repo on github (https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) in my own project, ran npm install, went to start my local server, and I am still getting an error (No bower.json present).

I have experience using browserify/grunt/gulp and other node dependencies to help me host a server locally and build a project, but I am still having issues here.

I am excited to start building locally, but alas, I cannot. Any help to unblock me here is MUCH appreciated.

Thx!

Comment: this is really not enough to give you any substantial help. However, if you are getting an error that says no bower.json present I would make sure of a couple of things #1 There is in fact a bower.json. #2 you are executing commands in the appropriate directory.

Comment: From Package Manager: "install-package bower"

Comment: Thanks for the reply..

There is a bower.json, but for some reason it will not load. I will go do some digging. Thanks for the help. I am new to stack overflow, so I will work on providing more info in my future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use either a python server or node.

If you have Python installed you can navigate to the folder with your index file and run the command:

python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000

Comment: ah. It turns out I had an error in one of my json files. Your answer caused me to start over with the installs and I fixed it. Thx!!!